# What is the algorithm behind Rasa NLU?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, nlu

I see the Rasa NLU use the MITIE and spaCy, but can anyone explain the how they use it and the algorithm behind?

Comment: RASA NLU doesn't use any algorithm as such. It uses [specific pipelines](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html) which you specify in the [configuration JSON file](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) for NER and intent recognition. One such pipeline is [sPacy](https://spacy.io/usage/examples) and another is [MITIE](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a post by Alan on the Rasa blog here that covers the basic approach used:
https://medium.com/rasa-blog/do-it-yourself-nlp-for-bot-developers-2e2da2817f3d

This should give a good idea of roughly what it's doing but if you are keen to find out more, you can easily look over the actual code used (which is the great advantage of open source solutions!) https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/tree/master/rasa_nlu

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of NER you want to use for your bot.. basically you define a pipeline in your configuration file ... most preferred is spacy since its corpus is being updated regularly and widely used .. mitie is not that good as compare to spacy and also is an older version.

> language: "en"
>
> pipeline: "spacy_sklearn"

you can read in more details here :
[choosing rasa nlu pipeline](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/choosing_pipeline/)